# Laço duplicando tabela inteira

Tags: php, html, loop

Não estou conseguindo fazer um laço na tabela, ela está fazendo laço a cada busca no banco.

```
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('senha_adm');
    $query = "select carro, barco, aviao, moto, triciclo, velotrou, dataCadastro from agencia";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>      

            <table id="tabela">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Carros</td>
                        <td>Barcos</td>
                        <td>Avioes</td>
                        <td>Motos</td>
                        <td>triciclos</td>
                        <td>Velotroes</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>  
                        <td><?php echo $row['carro']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['barco']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['aviao']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['moto']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['triciclo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['velotrou']; ?></td>

                    </tr>

            <?php       

           }


    echo " </table>";
```

Comment: Primeiro tenta elaborar melhor a pergunta, ao invés de apenas colar o código apenas. E como sugestão, use o título para informar de forma resumida o problema. Senao fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Geralmente o foreach é colocado na `<tr>`.

Comment: Melhor você rever seu código esse While com toda uma tabela, com ID ainda, dentro e com muito html dentro não é bom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tem que tirar o table e o cabeçalho do loop:

```
<?php
   ...

   $dbc = mysqli_connect('senha_adm');
   $query = "select carro, barco, aviao, moto, triciclo, velotrou, dataCadastro from agencia";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
?>
   <table id="tabela">
      <tr>
         <th>Carros</th>
         <th>Barcos</th>
         <th>Avioes</th>
         <th>Motos</th>
         <th>triciclos</th>
         <th>Velotroes</th>
      </tr>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
      <tr>  
         <td><?php echo $row['carro']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['barco']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['aviao']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['moto']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['triciclo']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['velotrou']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
   </table>
   ...
```

1. Você abre a tabela, mostra os cabeçalhos uma vez só.
2. Dentro do `while` é que cria várias `tr`, à medida que lê os dados.
3. Finalmente, fora do `while`, fecha a tabela.

Só para completar, troquei os `td` do cabeçalho por `th`, que é o mais adequado.